# Sending NSImage to AS3. AIR Native Extension(ANE)

Tags: objective-c, macos, actionscript-3, air-native-extension

In my native objective-c code I have a `NSImage`. How can I send it to as3 code, so I could use `addChild(NSImageFromNative)` method in my as3 project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to your solution, you can create a BitmapData in native code like that:

```
// first get those values from NSImage
FREObject contructorArguments[4] = { width, height, transparent, fillColor };

// create an instance of BitmapData
FREObject freBitmapData;
FRENewObject((uint8_t *)"flash.display.BitmapData", 4, contructorArguments, &freBitmapData, NULL);

// now acquire the bitmap data in order to manipulate it
FREBitmapData acquiredFreBitmapData;
FREAcquireBitmapData(freBitmap, &acquiredFreBitmapData);
```

After that you can copy pixels from NSImage to FREBitmapData.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found solution. Not sure if it is the best solution, but it works for me.
I just smashed the image on the pixels and combined it in action script code.

First, we need to convert NSImage to NSMutableArray consisting of pixel colors in hex:

```
NSImage *image = //Some image;

NSBitmapImageRep *imgRep = [[image representations] objectAtIndex: 0];
NSMutableArray *points = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //Points array

for(int i=0; i < [imgRep pixelsHigh]; i++){
    NSMutableArray *rows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int j=0; j<[imgRep pixelsWide]; j++){
        NSColor *color = [imgRep colorAtX:i y:j];
        NSString* hexString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02X%02X%02X",
            (int) (color.redComponent * 0xFF),
            (int) (color.greenComponent * 0xFF),
            (int) (color.blueComponent * 0xFF)];
        [rows addObject:hexString];
        }
        [points addObject:rows];
    }
```

Now we have an array with width*height points.
Then we need to send this array into our as3 code:

```
DEFINE_ANE_FUNCTION(getPixelArray){

FREObject row;
FREObject array;

NSMutableArray *points = //points array
FRENewObject((const uint8_t*)"Array", 0, NULL, &array, NULL);
for (int i=0; i<[points count]; i++){
    FRENewObject((const uint8_t*)"Array", 0, NULL, &row, NULL);
    for (int j=0; j<[[points objectAtIndex:i] count]; j++){
        NSString *pixel = points[i][j];
        const char *utf8String = pixel.UTF8String;
        FREObject pixelColor;
        FRENewObjectFromUTF8( strlen(utf8String), (uint8_t*) utf8String, &pixelColor);
        FRESetArrayElementAt(row, j, pixelColor);
    }
    FRESetArrayElementAt(array, i, row);
}

return array;
```

}

And now we can make a Bitmap in as3 code like this:

```
private function getImageFromNative: Bitmap{

    var ar: Array = extCtx.call("getPixelArray") as Array;
    var bm:BitmapData = new BitmapData(ar.length, (ar[0] as Array).length, false, 0);
    bm.lock();
    for (var i: int = 0; i<ar.length; i++){
        for (var j: int = 0; j<(ar[i] as Array).length; j++){
            var colorString: String = ar[i][j] as String;
            var color: uint = uint("0x" + colorString);
            bm.setPixel(i,j,color);
        }
    }
    bm.unlock()
    return new Bitmap(bm);
}
```

Yeah! Now we can add this bitmap to DisplayObjectContainer from our project. We just need to use something like this:

```
var na: MyAwesomeNativeExtension = new MyAwesomeNativeExtension();
this.addChild(na.getImageFromNative);
```

By this way 256x256 image is drawn for 20~30 milliseconds.

And sorry for my English.